# Clean dependencies for setup of a Python package with C++ extensions using Torch

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, setup.py, python-c-api

I have inherited a Python package with Torch-powered C++ extensions and I am trying to find my way around its installation and build process. I am a bit out of my depth, I haven't worked with compiled extensions before.

Currently, its `setup.py` imports `torch.utils.cpp_extension` to define how the system is built. Obviously, the import happens before the actual call to `setup`, so a dependency resolver like `pip` has no chance to install `torch` before executing the `setup.py`.

I am tempted to ask how to use `torch.utils.cpp_extension` in `setup.py` without assuming that Torch is installed ([that question has already been asked an answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715799/how-to-specify-dependencies-that-setup-py-needs-during-installation)), but I think what I actually want to know is the following:

What is the future-proof way to describe the build and install process of a Python package with C++ extensions using Torch, such that a `pip install /my/local/packagepath` should work out of the box?

I hope I am not asking too much. I'm happy to shift away from legacy `setup.py` and `setuptools`.